# How to build query with successive order methods

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am getting error for building query with chaining order methods as it has a return type of void.

```
  final qc =
        Entity_.objectID
            .equals(objectId)
            .and(Entity_.date
                .lessOrEqual(date.millisecondsSinceEpoch));

   final  QueryBuilder qBuilder = _box
        .query(qc)
        .order(DualPhaseOilWaterTankReadingData_.readingNumber)
        .order(DualPhaseOilWaterTankReadingData_.readingDate).build();

   
    List<Entity> data = qBuilder.find();
    qBuilder.close();
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use special Dart syntax ([cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation)) to "chain the `order` method calls:

```
final QueryBuilder qBuilder = _box.query(qc)
  ..order(DualPhaseOilWaterTankReadingData_.readingNumber)
  ..order(DualPhaseOilWaterTankReadingData_.readingDate);
final query = qBuilder.build();
```